# Acessar o banco SQLite (e outros tipos de armazenamento) do emulador

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app que usa o `SQLite, SharedPreferences, etc`.

Em meu aparelho com acesso `root` eu consigo acessar todas essas informações com alguns app's específicos para isso (que necessitam acesso root), principalmente o banco para ver se a tabela e os registros estão sendo criados corretamente.

**Existe alguma forma de acessar essas informações do emulador do Android Studio ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. Basta acessar o menu do Android Studio: `View` > `Tool Windows` > `Device File Explorer`

Answer (score 0):

Abra o CMD;
Acesse \platform-tools;
Execute "adb devices" para receber um lista com seus devices conectados;
Execute "adb -s  shell" para conectar a seu device; 
Execute "cd /data/data//databases" para acessar a pasta do database;
Execute "sqlite3 .db" para acessar o DB.

Obs: para sair do SQLITE3 digite ".exit".